# DatabaseGenerated Guid too predictable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, guid

I took a look to the guids generated by the data annotation

> DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)

in my sql database. It is too predictable and I would like something more proffesional. Any ideas how I could implement this?

[image: screenshot guids]

Thanks in advace.

Comment: In your model class you can also set the default value of your Id field to `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` for a more randomized GUID

Comment: guid is not meant to be unpredictable. Its meant to be not colliding, that holds in this case.

Comment: It is a feature, it maintains sort order by insertion order.  Much easier to deal with when you need to find bad data that recently crashed a program.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
}

public class SomeClass : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```